# Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate java.time.LocalDateTime.toString()

Tags: android, json, kotlin, sharedpreferences

In my android app with kotlin, i use a login interfece which I put Email and Password. After a success authetication, I want to stock this User with SharedPreferences. 
The User has as attribute: birthday,lastlogin and registrationdate of type of "LocalDateTime" and others of type String.
The following function, is to set the user in sharedpreferences with keyvalue "lastUser" :

```
private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
            context.getSharedPreferences(context.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    fun setUserByKeyValue(key: String,user: UsersData?) {
        val jsonString = Gson().toJson(user)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

        editor.putString(key, jsonString).apply()
    }
```

The problem is here as the following with the localdatetime:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate java.time.LocalDateTime.toString()
```

Comment: Verify that your registrationdate is not null. If it is null, maybe that is causing the error.

Comment: it's not null, only these attributes of LocaldateTime will change to null

Comment: The snippet you've attached doesn't include any references to `LocalDateTime`, so it's hard to tell what exactly is causing the error.